# Chapter 3, Problem 3.5 of Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

The problem states the following.

Suppose that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $F'(x)$ exists for *every* $x\in(a,b)$, and $F'(x)$ is integrable. Then $F$ is absolutely continuous and

$$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b F'(x)dx.$$

It comes with the following hint:

Assume $F'(x)\ge0$ for almost every $x$. We want to conclude that $F(b)\ge F(a)$. Let $E$ be the set of measure 0 of those $x$ such that $F'(x)<0$. Then according to Exercise 25, there is a function $\Phi$ which is increasing, absolutely continuous, and for which $D^+\Phi=+\infty$ on $E$, where $D^+$ is the right upper Dini derivative. Consider $F+\delta\Phi$, for each $\delta$ and apply the results (a) in Exercise 23 (which says $D^+f\ge0\implies F$ increasing).

While I can find the proof of the statement in other sources (e.g. Theorem 7.21 in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*), I cannot make *this particular hint* work. A natural attempt is to define

$$G(x)=F(a)+\int_a^x F'(t)dt$$

and consider $F-G$. Then this function is merely differentiable *almost* everywhere with derivative almost everywhere zero. *A priori* we cannot conclude $F-G=0$ due to the counterexample of the Cantor-Lebesgue function. Thus it is desirable to apply the hinted lemma, which, although not explicitly stated, seems to require the function in question to be differentiable *everywhere*, and is not directly applicable to $F-G$.

Therefore I am asking for a proof of the statement *along the lines of the provided hint*.

Comment: Looks very similar of continuous density functions in probability, maybe proofs regarding that would be useful to look up?